# Why is my localhost not 127.0.0.1 but ::1, and what notation is that?

Tags: windows, networking, ping, localhost, cmd.exe

When I use the Ping command against my localhost (on Windows Vista), it doesn't show up as 127.0.0.1.

> C:\Windows\system32>ping localhost
>   Pinging GIGA [::1] from ::1 with 32 bytes of data:

[image: ping pong]

Instead, it shows up as `::1` (pair of colons and a one). What kind of notation is this? And why is it not showing up as 127.0.0.1?

Here's what I see in the `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

```
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

As suggested by [Gregg](https://superuser.com/questions/667955/how-to-test-the-throughput-between-2-network-adapters-on-the-same-pc#comment844404_667968) I have already tried changing this order.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

The expected result is that `127.0.0.1` would take precedence over `::1` but that was not the case.

As I have learned now, this can be done by [adding](https://superuser.com/a/436944/137165) a prefix policy instead. To force cmd to use IP version 4 the option `-4` can be used. To force Windows to always use IP version 4, IP version 6 or some of its components can be disabled through the properties dialog for the network adapter or through a [registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852) tweak.

Comment: In Tom Wijsman's answer you'll find out http://superuser.com/questions/414050/why-is-there-a-difference-between-ping-localhost-and-ping-local-ip-address

Comment: Not only is that IPv6, but there is nothing special or hard-coded about `localhost`; it is specified in the [`HOSTS` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). It is `127.0.0.1` by default, but you can change it to whatever you want, or remove it altogether.

Comment: @Synetech on Windows 7 it's commented out by default with a note: `localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This is because ping on Windows Vista and newer Windows uses [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) by default when available. `::1` is a shortened notation of IPv6 loopback address - equivalent of IPv4 loopback `127.0.0.1`.

The full notation of the abbreviated `::1` IPv6 address is `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001`.

If you want to force [`ping`](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/ping-command.htm) to use IPv4 instead you can specify the IPv4 address explicitly or use the `-4` option.

```
ping 127.0.0.1
ping -4 localhost
```

If you want to change the IPv6/IPv4 preference overall you can check [IPv4 vs IPv6 priority in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/436944/61370).

For additional information you can also see the article [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Answer (score 18):

`[::1]` is shorthand for loopback address in IPv6.  If you would like to disable IPv6 for some reason (I would **not** advise it, but you may have a specific reason for wanting it), all you need to do is the following (for Windows 7):

- Start, Control Panel
- Network and Sharing
- View Active Network, Local Area Connection, Properties
- Uncheck the checkbox next to Internet Network Protocol Version 6

If you'd like screenshots, a guide from Microsoft can be found here: [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852).

Additionally, you may also want to take a look at the Wikipedia Page for IPv6, specifically, [Presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Presentation):

> The localhost (loopback) address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, and the IPv6
>   unspecified address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, are reduced to ::1 and ::,
>   respectively. This two-colon replacement may only be applied once in
>   an address, because multiple occurrences would create an ambiguous
>   representation.

To summarize, this is basically the equivalent of wanting to write every number 1 to 100, but instead of writing out every number individually, instead you write `1, 2, 3...99, 100` or `1-100`

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows#using-the-network-properties-gui-to-disable-ipv6-is-not-supported.  Testing also confirms that unchecking the IP6 checkboxes on network adapters no longer works in Windows 10.